# How to determine steps_per_epoch while using Image augumentation as it increase the number of images

Tags: deep-learning, keras

```
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train,y_train,batch_size=32),epochs=10,steps_per_epoch=5000,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

My total data size is 5000 and batch size is 32 , Then how to determine value for steps_per_epoch

case 1:When not using ImageAugumentation

cas2 2:When using using ImageAugumentation(Coz number images will increase and how to include that in steps_per_epoch)

Comment: In both the cases, it will be the same `5000//32`. The augmentation is done on the fly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `steps_per_epoch` will be the total number of samples in your training set (before augmentation) divided by the batch size. So--

```
steps_per_epoch = 5000 / 32 ~ 156
```

Using data augmentation will not affect this calculation. You can also get more info about working with this parameter, as well as the `fit_generator()`, in my video on [Training a CNN with Keras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daovGOlMbT4&index=11&list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrwRnXk_yCPtnqqo4_u2YGL). The `steps_per_epoch` coverage starts around 4:08.